# LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath

Tags: java, logging, spring-security, spring-boot, dependency-management

I think some module in spring-boot-starter-security is conflict with log4j, but I don't know which one.

my gradle dependence is as following:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"){
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
}

compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api"
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core"
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl"
compile('org.apache.poi:poi:3.10.1')
compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.10.1')
testCompile("junit:junit")
```

Comment: This article helped me to better understand and solve the problem:
https://tedblob.com/loggerfactory-is-not-a-logback-loggercontext-but-logback-is-on-the-classpath/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

i figured out

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"){
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
    exclude module: "logback-classic"
}
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"){
    exclude module: "logback-classic"
}
```

Comment: also applies to webflux `compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: '2.2.6.RELEASE') { // exclude modules }`

Comment: ... and also for `spring-boot-starter-mail`, `spring-boot-starter-mongodb`, `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, . Phew!

Answer (score 64):

Same solution for maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I came across the same with spring-kaka-test

Answer (score 38):

The problem for me went on with: Either remove Logback or the competing implementation class org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.0.jar

I added

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-to-slf4j'
    }
}
```

to my gradle.build and also refreshed all project dependencies with the latest versions and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 16):

Using the IDEA "Show Dependencies" or `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to find all the logback-classic jar file, and exclude them.

Comment: why talk about maven when the question is about gradle?

Comment: gradle dependencies

Comment: In my case I searched for all "log" dependencies and exclude slf4j-log4j12.

Answer (score 7):

Started seeing this error after including `'it.ozimov:embedded-redis:0.7.3'` I had to change

```
testImplementation 'it.ozimov:embedded-redis:0.7.3'
```

to

```
testImplementation ('it.ozimov:embedded-redis:0.7.3') {
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'slf4j-simple'
}
```

and the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

```
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

For me this was the fix, because OpenAPI Generator was bringing this and it conflicted with SpringsBoot Default.
So once I excluded this one, the SpringBootApp started working.

Comment: For gradle, `implementation("org.openapitools:openapi-generator:6.0.1"){
        exclude(group = "slf4j-simple", module = "slf4j-simple")
    }`

Comment: Thank you, including this tag within the openaiapi dependency fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

For me this problem appeared only during execution of maven-surefire-plugin. Somehow Logback is there on the class path, even if its not added to project dependencies. I added such fix:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
     <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem>
                org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem
            </org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can also use

```
mvn clean install -Dorg.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem=org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem
```

Comment: Will do my bit: in my case it was because of a "java-gradle-plugin" in gradle plugins section

Answer (score 2):

According to this [documentation](https://tedblob.com/loggerfactory-is-not-a-logback-loggercontext-but-logback-is-on-the-classpath/), Spring Boot automatically configures the Log Back library because of the web starter. You should exclude the spring-boot-starter-logging to fix the issue.

To exclude the default LogBack configuration on the gradle project,

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    all*.exclude module : 'logback-classic'
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer! But you should consider [editting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69718362/edit) it to include a quote of the reference you included. This will make your answer more robust in case the reference you link to disappears.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this bug](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13788), the bundled and undeletable Kotlin plugin (reminds me the forced inclusion of U2's album with iOS) includes `org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl`, which in turn pollutes the classpath with an incompatible logging library (even if disabled).

I solved this by changing the runner from "IntelliJ IDEA" to "Gradle" in preferences:

- Build, Execution, Deployment

  - Build Tools

    - Gradle

      - Build an run using -> Gradle
      - Run tests using -> Gradle

Answer (score 0):

works for me:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- avoid: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. on run with vscode -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per @Bohemian 's post:

Removing this fixed it for me:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

[Bug reference](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13788) from @Bohemian

This plugin is recommended to be added to gradle files for the kotlin dsl, but I found that it really isn't needed... syntax highlighting still worked for me afterwards and I didn't see any issues after removing it. In fact it removed the issue mentioned in this thread to remove it.

Answer (score -2):

It should be told that after trying to exclude every logback artifact I found which didn't work for me, I just deleted the maven-folder  (/.m2). After another

```
mvn clean install
```

everything started fine and the error never appeared again. I by the way removed every Exclusion i did before. Still working