# Wildfly upgrade RuntimeException - LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is - Any solution for wildfly-24.0.1.Final?

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly

I would like to upgrade the Wildfly version I'm using for my Spring boot projects.
This to go from "wildfly-21.0.2.Final" to "wildfly-24.0.1.Final".
But, if I don't add the following exclusion to all the spring boot dependencies :

```
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
```

I end up with the following RuntimeException :

> [0m[31m18:13:11,977 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 86) MSC000001: Failed to start service
> jboss.deployment.unit."en74-t2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment:
> org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
> jboss.deployment.unit."en74-t2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the
> classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation
> (class org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory loaded from
> jar:file:/home/rbh/wildfly-24.0.1.Final-20220216-18h12/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/impl/main/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final.jar!/).
> If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to
> prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml:
> org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory     at
> org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:90)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)  at
> org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback
> LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback
> or the competing implementation (class
> org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory loaded from
> jar:file:/home/rbh/wildfly-24.0.1.Final-20220216-18h12/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/impl/main/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final.jar!/).
> If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to
> prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml:
> org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory     at
> io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)

I have found the solution of the exclusion with the answers of the following question :

[LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792268/loggerfactory-is-not-a-logback-loggercontext-but-logback-is-on-the-classpath)

But this solution stops Spring boot writting in the logs all together.
This doesn't help if you want to see the errors displayed by Spring boot or if you want to put some information in the logs.

The problem can be better understood with the 6 files in this repository :

https://github.com/aiHFL/for-stackoverflow-question-num-01.git

Is there another way to change the pom.xml file or other so that we don't have this RuntimeException ?

Rémi

Comment: It looks like you will need to add the exclusion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984009/disable-logback-in-springboot and see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4341#issuecomment-335478846