# LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Deploy Spring-Boot Application on Wildfly

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, log4j, wildfly

I am trying to deploy a Spring-Boot Vaadin java application on a Wildfly server with a .war.
Unfortunately I always get this error message:

```
2022-04-28 00:23:18,113 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation](DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"planyoureplaylist-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory loaded from jar:file:/C:/ude/Wildfly/wildfly-26.1.0.Final/wildfly-26.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/impl/main/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final.jar!/). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory loaded from jar:file:/C:/ude/Wildfly/wildfly-26.1.0.Final/wildfly-26.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/impl/main/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final.jar!/). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory loaded from jar:file:/C:/ude/Wildfly/wildfly-26.1.0.Final/wildfly-26.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/impl/main/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final.jar!/). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory"}}
2022-04-28 00:23:18,181 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2)WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "planyoureplaylist-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" with deployment "planyoureplaylist-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
2022-04-28 00:23:18,182 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service  jboss.deployment.unit."planyoureplaylist-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".undertow-deployment:  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a  Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the  competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory loaded from jar:file:/C:/ude/Wildfly/wildfly-26.1.0.Final/wildfly-26.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j /impl/main/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.1.0.Final.jar!/). If you are using WebLogic you will  need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml:      org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory`
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<!-- Vaadin project from https://start.vaadin.com/project/1a8943e6-3b51-4088-a8f4-4c3a070f7245 -->
<groupId>com.planyoureplaylist.application</groupId>
<artifactId>planyoureplaylist</artifactId>
<name>Project base for Spring Boot and Vaadin Flow</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <vaadin.version>14.7.5</vaadin.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</parent>

<repositories>
    <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

    <!-- Main Maven repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
    <repository>
        <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <!-- Main Maven repository -->
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Excluding so that webjars are not included. -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
        <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly.plugins/wildfly-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Include JUnit 4 support for TestBench and others -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>se.michaelthelin.spotify</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotify-web-api-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fracpete</groupId>
        <artifactId>jclipboardhelper</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-clean-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
            <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                 the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
            <configuration>
                <wait>500</wait>
                <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!--
            Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
            package.json and main.js files.
            It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>it</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>start</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                        <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>.</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>package.json</include>
                                    <include>package-lock.json</include>
                                    <include>webpack.config.js</include>
                                    <include>webpack.generated.js</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>./node_modules</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/**</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

I already tried to exclude any maven dependency with logfj.
But nothing helps...

I am also not sure if my problem is due to the loger statements present in the classes.
An example would be:

> log.info("Songs deleted from UserPLaylist.");

Sorry for my bad English. :)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you just need do exclude the dependency
[similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792268/loggerfactory-is-not-a-logback-loggercontext-but-logback-is-on-the-classpath)

Comment: That link should work. You need to exclude logback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search I finally solved the problem.
The problem was caused by two reasons.

1:
For my logger functions I used a library which is not integrated by Wildfly.
Therefore I decided to use the logger of the Wildfly.
Maven Dependnency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My logger method now looks like this:

```
 private static final Logger log =Logger.getLogger(PlaylistService.class);
 log.info("Get UserPlaylist form Database.");
```

2:
Due to an already intergeirte dependency of Vaadin there was a misunderstanding which logger library the Wildfly should use.
By the statement:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

I could remove the duplicate and not needed libaries (in this case the slf4j in the io.github.bonigarcia).
So look over the Maven tree again in your application and remove the duplicate dependencies with an "exclusion" in your pom.xml.

Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Because the logging framework from spring boot is conflicted with Wildfly's.

Normally you would just exclude it from spring-boot-starter-web dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Or if you like to use `logback` instead of Wildfly's logging system, you can add a [`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`](https://docs.wildfly.org/27/Developer_Guide.html#jboss-deployment-structure-file) under the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` directory. It basically tells the Wildfly not to use their logging system on your deployment:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <subsystem name="logging" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

See [Wildfly Admin Guide](https://docs.wildfly.org/27/Admin_Guide.html#how-do-i-log4j2)