# Vaadin 24 front end development bundle throwing a DOMException due to 'vaadin-button' being already used with this registry

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23, vaadin24

I am updating my vaadin application from 23.3 to 24 and spring version to 3.0.4.

I have found that when running my application locally I receive an error inside the browser, see below:

***Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "vaadin-button" has already been used with this registry
at window.customElements.define (http://localhost:8080/login:4:829)
at http://localhost:8080/VAADIN/dev-bundle/VAADIN/build/generated-flow-imports-4b2e9ecd.js:3435:406***

**Below is where it reports the error is:**

```
class Button extends ButtonMixin(ElementMixin$1(ThemableMixin(ControllerMixin(PolymerElement)))) {
static get is() {
    return "vaadin-button"
}
static get template() {
    return buttonTemplate(html$1)
}
ready() {
    super.ready(),
    this._tooltipController = new TooltipController(this),
    this.addController(this._tooltipController)
}
}

customElements.define(Button.is, Button);
```

**My pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>uk.co.dhl</groupId>
<artifactId>smas</artifactId>
<name>Supervised Manufacturing</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <vaadin.version>24.0.0</vaadin.version>

    <drivers.dir>${project.basedir}/drivers</drivers.dir>
    <drivers.downloader.phase>pre-integration-test</drivers.downloader.phase>

    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>

    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>

    <log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</parent>

<repositories>
    <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

    <!-- Main Maven repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
    <repository>
        <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <!-- Main Maven repository -->
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-icons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-icons</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Excluding so that webjars are not included. -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.componentfactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>svg</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
        <version>8.16.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--database dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <!-- Exclusion added to stop the logger having a fight with itself, see:-->
        <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792268/loggerfactory-is-not-a-logback-`loggercontext-but-logback-is-on-the-classpath/59985914-->`
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!--        <dependency>-->
    <!--            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>-->
    <!--            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>-->
    <!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
    <!--        </dependency>-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.jre11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--security dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--validation dependencies -->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Testing dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
    <finalName>
        ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${git.commit.id.describe-short}-${git.branch}-${maven.build.timestamp}
    </finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                 the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
            <configuration>
                <wait>500</wait>
                <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!--
            Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
            package.json and main.js files.
            It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
        -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>15</source>
                <target>15</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${git-commit-id-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>get-the-git-infos</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>revision</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <jvmArguments>-Dvaadin.productionMode</jvmArguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>integration-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>start</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                        <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <!-- Pass location of downloaded webdrivers to the tests -->
                            <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.17</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>true
                        </onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>
                        <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                            ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver
                        </rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                        <downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                            ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver_zips
                        </downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                        <customRepositoryMap>
                            ${project.basedir}/drivers.xml
                        </customRepositoryMap>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <!-- use phase "none" to skip download step -->
                            <phase>${drivers.downloader.phase}</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>selenium</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>
```

This problem has only occurred for me since moving to Vaadin 24 and the auto generated "dev-bundle" is added.

If anyone could shed some light on why this message appears and possible solutions it would be much appreciated. If there is anything else I should include into this question please let me know.

Comment: That Vaadin icons dependency doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried removing vaadin-icons dependency and running it again but the same issue persists.

Comment: You can also enable hot deploy again to see if it's just related to the dev-bundle.

Answer (score 1):

The version of the svg component is quite old and depends on an old version of a vaadin button. The latest version of the component is 1.1.1 but it has been released in September 2021. I think the component is not working in Vaadin 23 or 24.
There is a ticket here: https://github.com/vaadin-component-factory/svg/issues/18

Comment: Thank you for answering. I suspect this is my problem, unfortunately that SVG component is everywhere in my application at the moment so once I have replaced it, I will try again.